# Entity Framework and Oracle Client - Issue with stored procedure

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4, plsql

I am using Entity Framework with Oracle in a project and trying to call a stored procedure from EF. The procedure goes as

```
Create or Replace Procedure usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select(
    p_afdelingId in varchar2,
    p_productTypeId in varchar2,
    p_productieData out sys_refcursor)
IS 
Begin
    Open p_productieData for
        Select rp.Batchnummer, cppo.Productnummer, p.Omschrijving, pra.Bruto_In_Meters
        From Rotaplateproductie rp inner join Productieresultaatrtplrol pra
        on rp.Batchnummer = pra.Batchnummer inner join Cpiplusproductieorder cppo
        on pra.ProductieNummer = cppo.ProductNummer inner join Product p
        on cppo.Productnummer = p.Productnummer Where rp.Afdelingid = p_afdelingId
        and rp.producttype = p_productTypeId; 
END;
```

But when EF executes the function I am getting the error below

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'USP_ROTAPLATEPRODUCTIE_SELECT.
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PL / SQL: Statement IGNORED.
```

I am calling this procedure using the below code

```
public ObjectResult<RotaPlateProductie> Search_RotaPlateProductie(global::System.String p_AFDELINGID, global::System.String p_PRODUCTTYPEID)
    {
        ObjectParameter p_AFDELINGIDParameter;
        if (p_AFDELINGID != null)
        {
            p_AFDELINGIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("P_AFDELINGID", p_AFDELINGID);
        }
        else
        {
            p_AFDELINGIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("P_AFDELINGID", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        ObjectParameter p_PRODUCTTYPEIDParameter;
        if (p_PRODUCTTYPEID != null)
        {
            p_PRODUCTTYPEIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("P_PRODUCTTYPEID", p_PRODUCTTYPEID);
        }
        else
        {
            p_PRODUCTTYPEIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("P_PRODUCTTYPEID", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction<RotaPlateProductie>("Search_RotaPlateProductie", p_AFDELINGIDParameter, p_PRODUCTTYPEIDParameter);
    }
```

Here RotaPlateProductie is the entity from which I am binding the result set
Please help.

Comment: how do you call the procedure? the error is saying that you called the procedure with wrong number or type of arguments, and what is the purpose of your procedure? could you give more details?

Comment: @mcha - Using EF's function import, I pulled out the SP in Model code behind, and using Context.FunctionName I am calling that procedure with the required input params. Let me know if u need more info

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code which sets up the parameters and calls the stored procedure. Thanks. Also, was this procedure modified and an argument added or removed after your did the import?

Comment: @BobJarvis - Added the code. Between the procedure was not modified after function import

Comment: How is your code dealing with the P_PRODUCTIEDATA output parameter?  There's no mention of it in the calling code.

Comment: @BobJarvis - I am not sure how to deal with this. Though by googling,I found a link, where the author asked to put some details in app setings like <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="SYSADM.USP_ROTAPLATEPRODUCTIE_SEARCH.RefCursor.P_PRODUCTIEDATA" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />
<add name="SYSADM.USP_ROTAPLATEPRODUCTIE_SEARCH.RefCursor.P_PRODUCTIEDATA.Column.0"
        value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=BatchNummer;NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, except that it looks like this isn't setting up the P_PRODUCTIEDATA parameter for the procedure call.  Can you change Search_RotaPlateProductie to be a FUNCTION and make the return value the desired SYS_REFCURSOR?

Comment: @BobJarvis Oracle Function is not supported in EF

Answer (score 2):

You must add configuration;iIn your case should be as follows:

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client
    <settings>
      <add name="rp.usp_RotaPlateProductie_Select.RefCursor.p_productieData" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />...
   <settings>
</oracle.dataaccess.client
```